# Has Anyone Used ISPconfig 3

Tags: webserver

I just upgraded to 12.04 and was contemplating on installing ISPconfig3 and was wondering if anyone has used ISPconfig3 and how does it perform. Please and Thank You in advance....

Comment: There is no mention of Ubuntu in this post, so I am closing as off-topic. Please ask at [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com).

Comment: Im using ISPConfig3 for my ubuntu server. And yes it was great!

Answer (score 0):

Yes I have ISPConfig3 running on Ubuntu 12.04, easy install, easy configuration and not much overhead. It's a great tool for easy standard management of your server, I can recommend it.

Comment: Can you provide more details?